# Symfony service strict parameter

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

Does anyone know what the "strict" parameter does when injecting a service in Symfony ?

For example:

```
<service ...>
    <argument type="service" id="whatever" strict=false />
</service>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where have you seen `strict` parameter used? It doesn't seem to be in the documentation.

Comment: I saw it being used in a project I am currently working on, but no one seems to know what it does :) I did not find it in the Symfony docs either, only a couple of mentions of "strict services", but without any explanation at to what those might be. Also found it as an accepted parameter in the argument tag definion seen here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some research and it's a [leftover from Symfony 2.8 as this comment suggests](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Reference.php#L26):

> Note: The $strict parameter is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0.

Since 3.0 the parameter doesn't exist as well as the deprecation warning but classes [`YamlFileLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L469) and [`XmlFileLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php#L376) still read it even though the [`Reference`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Reference.php) class takes only two arguments.

So, this parameter does nothing :).